# Python3 process and display webcam stream at the webcams fps

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, tkinter

How can I read a camera and display the images at the cameras frame rate?

I want to continuously read images from my webcam, (do some fast preprocessing) and then display the image in a window. This should run at the frame rate, that my webcam provides (29 fps).
It seems like the OpenCV GUI and Tkinter GUI is too slow, to display images at such a frame rate. These are clearly the bottlenecks in my experiments. Even without the preprocessing, the images are not displayed fast enough. I am on a MacBook Pro 2018.

Here is what I tried. The webcam is always read with OpenCV:

- Everything happens in the main thread, the images are displayed with OpenCV: 12 fps
- Read camera and do preprocessing in separate threads, show image with OpenCV in the main thread: 20 fps
- multithreaded like above, but do not show the image: 29 fps
- multithreaded like above, but show the images with Tkinter: don't know the exact fps but it feels like <10 fps.

Here is the code:

Single loop, OpenCV GUI:

```py
import cv2
import time


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    window_name = "FPS Single Loop"
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    start_time = time.time()
    frames = 0

    seconds_to_measure = 10
    while start_time + seconds_to_measure > time.time():
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = img[:, ::-1]  # mirror
        time.sleep(0.01)  # simulate some processing time
        cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        frames = frames + 1

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    print(
        f"Captured {frames} in {seconds_to_measure} seconds. FPS: {frames/seconds_to_measure}"
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`Captured 121 in 10 seconds. FPS: 12.1`

Multithreaded, opencv gui:

```py
import logging
import time
from queue import Full, Queue
from threading import Thread, Event

import cv2

logger = logging.getLogger("VideoStream")


def setup_webcam_stream(src=0):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
    width, height = (
        cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
        cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT),
    )
    logger.info(f"Camera dimensions: {width, height}")
    logger.info(f"Camera FPS: {cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)}")
    grabbed, frame = cap.read()  # Read once to init
    if not grabbed:
        raise IOError("Cannot read video stream.")
    return cap


def video_stream_loop(video_stream: cv2.VideoCapture, queue: Queue, stop_event: Event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            success, img = video_stream.read()
            # We need a timeout here to not get stuck when no images are retrieved from the queue
            queue.put(img, timeout=1)
        except Full:
            pass  # try again with a newer frame


def processing_loop(input_queue: Queue, output_queue: Queue, stop_event: Event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            img = input_queue.get()
            img = img[:, ::-1]  # mirror
            time.sleep(0.01)  # simulate some processing time
            # We need a timeout here to not get stuck when no images are retrieved from the queue
            output_queue.put(img, timeout=1)
        except Full:
            pass  # try again with a newer frame


def main():
    stream = setup_webcam_stream(0)
    webcam_queue = Queue()
    processed_queue = Queue()
    stop_event = Event()
    window_name = "FPS Multi Threading"
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    start_time = time.time()
    frames = 0

    seconds_to_measure = 10
    try:
        Thread(
            target=video_stream_loop, args=[stream, webcam_queue, stop_event]
        ).start()
        Thread(
            target=processing_loop, args=[webcam_queue, processed_queue, stop_event]
        ).start()
        while start_time + seconds_to_measure > time.time():
            img = processed_queue.get()
            cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            frames = frames + 1
    finally:
        stop_event.set()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    print(
        f"Captured {frames} frames in {seconds_to_measure} seconds. FPS: {frames/seconds_to_measure}"
    )
    print(f"Webcam queue: {webcam_queue.qsize()}")
    print(f"Processed queue: {processed_queue.qsize()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

```
INFO:VideoStream:Camera dimensions: (1280.0, 720.0)
INFO:VideoStream:Camera FPS: 29.000049
Captured 209 frames in 10 seconds. FPS: 20.9
Webcam queue: 0
Processed queue: 82
```

Here you can see that there are images remaining in the second queue where the images get fetched for displaying them.

When I uncomment these two lines:

```
cv2.imshow(window_name, img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

then the output is:

```
INFO:VideoStream:Camera dimensions: (1280.0, 720.0)
INFO:VideoStream:Camera FPS: 29.000049
Captured 291 frames in 10 seconds. FPS: 29.1
Webcam queue: 0
Processed queue: 0
```

So it is able to process all frames at the webcams speed without a GUI displaying them.

Multithreaded, Tkinter gui:

```py
import logging
import time
import tkinter
from queue import Full, Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread, Event

import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2

logger = logging.getLogger("VideoStream")


def setup_webcam_stream(src=0):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
    width, height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    logger.info(f"Camera dimensions: {width, height}")
    logger.info(f"Camera FPS: {cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)}")
    grabbed, frame = cap.read()  # Read once to init
    if not grabbed:
        raise IOError("Cannot read video stream.")
    return cap, width, height


def video_stream_loop(video_stream: cv2.VideoCapture, queue: Queue, stop_event: Event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            success, img = video_stream.read()
            # We need a timeout here to not get stuck when no images are retrieved from the queue
            queue.put(img, timeout=1)
        except Full:
            pass  # try again with a newer frame


def processing_loop(input_queue: Queue, output_queue: Queue, stop_event: Event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            img = input_queue.get()
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = img[:, ::-1]  # mirror
            time.sleep(0.01)  # simulate some processing time
            # We need a timeout here to not get stuck when no images are retrieved from the queue
            output_queue.put(img, timeout=1)
        except Full:
            pass  # try again with a newer frame


class App:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title, image_queue: Queue, image_dimensions: tuple):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)

        self.image_queue = image_queue

        # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=image_dimensions[0], height=image_dimensions[1])
        self.canvas.pack()

        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        self.delay = 1
        self.update()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def update(self):
        try:
            frame = self.image_queue.get(timeout=0.1)  # Timeout to not block this method forever
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
            self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)
        except Empty:
            pass  # try again next time


def main():
    stream, width, height = setup_webcam_stream(0)
    webcam_queue = Queue()
    processed_queue = Queue()
    stop_event = Event()
    window_name = "FPS Multi Threading"

    try:
        Thread(target=video_stream_loop, args=[stream, webcam_queue, stop_event]).start()
        Thread(target=processing_loop, args=[webcam_queue, processed_queue, stop_event]).start()
        App(tkinter.Tk(), window_name, processed_queue, (width, height))
    finally:
        stop_event.set()

    print(f"Webcam queue: {webcam_queue.qsize()}")
    print(f"Processed queue: {processed_queue.qsize()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

```
INFO:VideoStream:Camera dimensions: (1280.0, 720.0)
INFO:VideoStream:Camera FPS: 29.000049
Webcam queue: 0
Processed queue: 968
```

Comment: Are you aware that in python "multithreaded" does not mean "executed simultaneously", because of the global interpreter lock?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I tried to look into multiprocessing, but stumbled onto more problems. One of these is, that GUI events should happen in the main thread. Im also not able to read the camera in a separate process. If there is a solution that uses multiprocessing or not multithreading, then I am very happy to hear about it.

Comment: I don't think multiprocessing is the way to go either, communication i just too complex (and I doubt it would still be performant enough). You need to find out what part of your script is the slow one and see what you can do about it. Since it runs at 30FPS without visualization, I suspect that might be the bottleneck. You might give Qt a try (via one of its python bindings), as that may both help you speeding things up, and possibly offer real multithreading. I don't think a pure python solution with GUI will be fast enough for 30FPS

Comment: Maybe combining OpenCV with Gstreamer is the way forward but it will require that you rewrite nearly everything.

Comment: What about Kivy + gstreamer? The `kivy.core.camera.camera_gi` can be initialized with gst elements linked with `!`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On this answer I share some considerations on *camera FPS* VS *display FPS* and some code examples that demonstrates:

- The basics on FPS calculation;
- How to increase the display FPS from **29 fps** to **300+ fps**;
- How to use `threading` and `queue` efficiently to capture at the closest maximum fps supported by the camera;

For anyone going through your issue, here is a couple of important questions that need to be answered first:

- What's the size of the images being captured?
- How many FPS does your webcam support? (*camera FPS*)
- How fast can you grab a frame from the webcam and display it in a window? (*display FPS*)

#### Camera FPS VS Display FPS

The **camera fps** refers to what the hardware of the camera is capable of. For instance, *ffmpeg* tells that at 640x480 my camera can return 15 fps minimum and 30 at maximum, among other formats:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="HP HD Camera"

[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=15 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=320x180 fps=15 max s=320x180 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=320x240 fps=15 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=424x240 fps=15 max s=424x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x360 fps=15 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=848x480 fps=15 max s=848x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=960x540 fps=15 max s=960x540 fps=30
[dshow @ 00000220181cc600]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=15 max s=1280x720 fps=30
```

The important realization here is that despite being able to capture 30 fps internally, there is NO guarantee that an application will be able to pull those 30 frames from the camera in a second. The reasons behind this are clarified on the following sections.

The **display fps** refers to how many images can be draw in a window per second. This number is not limited by the camera at all and its usually much much higher than the camera fps. As you'll see later, its possible to create and application that pulls 29 images per second from the camera and draws them more than 300 times a second. That means that the same image from the camera is drawn multiple times in a window before the next frame is pulled from the camera.

### How many FPS can my webcam capture?

The following application simply demonstrates how to print the default settings used by the camera (size, fps) and how to retrieve frames from it, display it in a window and compute the amount of FPS being rendered:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
    
def main():
    # create display window
    cv2.namedWindow("webcam", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    # initialize webcam capture object
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # retrieve properties of the capture object
    cap_width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    cap_height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    cap_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    fps_sleep = int(1000 / cap_fps)
    print('* Capture width:', cap_width)
    print('* Capture height:', cap_height)
    print('* Capture FPS:', cap_fps, 'ideal wait time between frames:', fps_sleep, 'ms')

    # initialize time and frame count variables
    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    frames = 0

    # main loop: retrieves and displays a frame from the camera
    while (True):
        # blocks until the entire frame is read
        success, img = cap.read()
        frames += 1

        # compute fps: current_time - last_time
        delta_time = datetime.datetime.now() - last_time
        elapsed_time = delta_time.total_seconds()
        cur_fps = np.around(frames / elapsed_time, 1)

        # draw FPS text and display image
        cv2.putText(img, 'FPS: ' + str(cur_fps), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow("webcam", img)

        # wait 1ms for ESC to be pressed
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if (key == 27):
            break

    # release resources
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
* Capture width: 640.0
* Capture height: 480.0
* Capture FPS: 30.0 wait time between frames: 33 ms
```

As mentioned earlier, my camera is able to capture 640x480 images at 30 fps by default and even though the loop above is pretty simple, my **display FPS** is lower: I'm only able to retrieve frames and display them at 28 or 29 fps and that's without performing any custom image processing in between. What's going on?

The reality is that even though the loop looks pretty simple, there are things happening under the hood that costs just enough processing time to make it difficult for one iteration of the loop to happen in less than 33ms:

- `cap.read()` executes I/O calls to the camera driver in order to pull the new data. This function blocks execution of your application until the data has been transferred completely;
- a numpy array needs to be setup with the new pixels;
- other calls are required to display a window and draw the pixels in it, namely `cv2.imshow()`, which is usually slow operation;
- there's also a 1ms delay thanks to `cv2.waitKey(1)` which is required to keep the window opened;

All of these operations, as small as they are, make it incredibly difficult for an application to call `cap.read()`, get a new frame and display it at precisely 30 fps.

There's a number of things you can try to speed up the application to be able to display more frames than the camera driver allows and [this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) covers them well. Just remember this: you won't be able to **capture more frames** from the camera than what the driver says it supports. You will, however, be able to **display more frames**.

### How to increase the *display FPS* to **300+**? A `threading` example.

One of the approaches used to increase the amount of images being displayed per second relies on the `threading` package to create a separate thread to continuously pull frames from the camera. This happens because the main loop of the application is not blocked on `cap.read()` anymore waiting for it to return a new frame, thus increasing the number of frames that can be displayed (or draw) per second.

**Note**: this approach renders the same image multiple times on a window until the next image from the camera is retrieved. Keep in mind that it might even draw an image while it's contents are still being updated with new data from the camera.

The following application is just an academic example, not something I recommend as production code, to increase the amount of frames per second that are display in a window:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
from threading import Thread

# global variables
stop_thread = False             # controls thread execution
img = None                      # stores the image retrieved by the camera


def start_capture_thread(cap):
    global img, stop_thread

    # continuously read fames from the camera
    while True:
        _, img = cap.read()

        if (stop_thread):
            break


def main():
    global img, stop_thread

    # create display window
    cv2.namedWindow("webcam", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    # initialize webcam capture object
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # retrieve properties of the capture object
    cap_width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    cap_height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    cap_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    fps_sleep = int(1000 / cap_fps)
    print('* Capture width:', cap_width)
    print('* Capture height:', cap_height)
    print('* Capture FPS:', cap_fps, 'wait time between frames:', fps_sleep)

    # start the capture thread: reads frames from the camera (non-stop) and stores the result in img
    t = Thread(target=start_capture_thread, args=(cap,), daemon=True) # a deamon thread is killed when the application exits
    t.start()

    # initialize time and frame count variables
    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    frames = 0
    cur_fps = 0

    while (True):
        # blocks until the entire frame is read
        frames += 1

        # measure runtime: current_time - last_time
        delta_time = datetime.datetime.now() - last_time
        elapsed_time = delta_time.total_seconds()

        # compute fps but avoid division by zero
        if (elapsed_time != 0):
            cur_fps = np.around(frames / elapsed_time, 1)

        # TODO: make a copy of the image and process it here if needed

        # draw FPS text and display image
        if (img is not None):
            cv2.putText(img, 'FPS: ' + str(cur_fps), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.imshow("webcam", img)

        # wait 1ms for ESC to be pressed
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if (key == 27):
            stop_thread = True
            break

    # release resources
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### How to capture at the closest maximum fps supported by the camera? A `threading` and `queue` example.

The problem of using a `queue` is that, performance-wise, what you get depends on how many frames per second the application can pull from the camera. If the camera supports 30 fps then that's what your application *might* get as long as the image processing operations being done are fast. Otherwise, there will be a drop in the number of frames being displayed (per second) and the size of the queue will slowly increase until all your RAM memory runs out. To avoid that problem, make sure to set `queueSize` with a number that prevents the queue from growing beyond what your OS can handle.

The following code is a naive implementation that creates a dedicated *thread* to grab frames from the camera and puts them in a *queue* that is later used by the main loop of the application:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
import queue
from threading import Thread

# global variables
stop_thread = False             # controls thread execution


def start_capture_thread(cap, queue):
    global stop_thread

    # continuously read fames from the camera
    while True:
        _, img = cap.read()
        queue.put(img)

        if (stop_thread):
            break


def main():
    global stop_thread

    # create display window
    cv2.namedWindow("webcam", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    # initialize webcam capture object
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    # retrieve properties of the capture object
    cap_width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    cap_height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    cap_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print('* Capture width:', cap_width)
    print('* Capture height:', cap_height)
    print('* Capture FPS:', cap_fps)

    # create a queue
    frames_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

    # start the capture thread: reads frames from the camera (non-stop) and stores the result in img
    t = Thread(target=start_capture_thread, args=(cap, frames_queue,), daemon=True) # a deamon thread is killed when the application exits
    t.start()

    # initialize time and frame count variables
    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    frames = 0
    cur_fps = 0

    while (True):
        if (frames_queue.empty()):
            continue

        # blocks until the entire frame is read
        frames += 1

        # measure runtime: current_time - last_time
        delta_time = datetime.datetime.now() - last_time
        elapsed_time = delta_time.total_seconds()

        # compute fps but avoid division by zero
        if (elapsed_time != 0):
            cur_fps = np.around(frames / elapsed_time, 1)

        # retrieve an image from the queue
        img = frames_queue.get()

        # TODO: process the image here if needed

        # draw FPS text and display image
        if (img is not None):
            cv2.putText(img, 'FPS: ' + str(cur_fps), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.imshow("webcam", img)

        # wait 1ms for ESC to be pressed
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if (key == 27):
            stop_thread = True
            break

    # release resources
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Earlier I said *might* and here is what I meant: even when I use a dedicated *thread* to pull frames from the camera and a *queue* to store them, the displayed fps is still capped to 29.3 when it should have been 30 fps. In this case, I assume that the camera driver or the backend implementation used by `VideoCapture` can be blamed for the issue. On Windows, the backend used by default is **MSMF**.

It is possible to force `VideoCapture` to use a different backend by passing the right arguments on the constructor:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

My experience with **DShow** was terrible: the returned `CAP_PROP_FPS` from the camera was **0** and the displayed FPS got stuck around **14**. This is just an example to illustrate how the backend capture driver can interfere negatively with the camera capture.

But that's something you can explore. Maybe using a different backend on your OS can provide better results. Here's a nice [high-level overview of the Video I/O module from OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) that lists the supported backends:

[image]

**Update**

In one of the comments of this answer, the OP upgraded OpenCV 4.1 to 4.3 on Mac OS and observed a noticeable improvement on FPS rendering. It looks like it was a performance issue related to `cv2.imshow()`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I also saw the post by pyimagesearch. My problem with that approach is, that the same frame gets displayed multiple times. So the framerate of the whole pipeline from capturing a frame to displaying it is not really running at 155 fps. I want to process each frame once, therefore I used the queue. You said the video capture backend or my processing could be blamed for the cap in fps. I think the displaying part is responsible for the cap in fps (see my experiments where I don't display the frames and the frame rate is high).

Comment: I was able to improve the performance of my last code in the answer to **29.3** FPS by changing the sleep time to 1ms in `cv2.waitKey()`. When I was using 5ms the FPS was capped at **27**.  It's interesting how such a small change impacts the performance of the application. By the way, that code uses the queue to process each frame only once. I also improved the formatting of the answer. Just make sure to use my FPS calculation algorithm to do your measurements.

Comment: The reality is that we need to understand that there is a difference between how many FPS a camera can capture internally using its firmware and how many FPS an application running on OS can get from that camera: 29.3 is close enough to 30 for most applications.

Comment: An alternative and radical approach is to get rid of `VideoCapture` and write your own code that communicates with the driver of the camera to retrieve the frames. That's your best shot to get that sweet FPS count supported by the camera.

Comment: I still believe that the display is what slows things down here (maybe just on a Mac?). When I replace `_, img = cap.read()` with `img = np.ones((720, 1280,3)` in your examples, then the FPS is at 28. When I resize the window, the fps drop significantly.

Comment: Also the example, that seems to run at 300+ FPS on your machine just outputs about 27 on mine.

Comment: There was an issue with `cv2.imshow()` on Mac OS X before OpenCV 4 that made it slow. Can you confirm that you are using OpenCV 4.x ?

Comment: My OpenCV version is 4.1.2
```import cv2
cv2.__version__
'4.1.2'```

Comment: At this point you can upgrade to OpenCV 4.3 or try to rebuild OpenCV yourself to try to use a different GUI backend.

Comment: Ok on opencv 4.3 it runs much faster. Single Loop 27 FPS, Queue 28.8 FPS. Maximum speed seems to be capped at 60 FPS though. I had opencv-python<4.2 in my requirements.txt. Can't remember why though. Thanks again for all of your help! Can you add a line regarding the version to the answer?